# Using variables in MySQL UPDATE (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, sql-update

I am using this code so I can update a record in database:

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE article 
                         SET com_count = ". $comments_count 
                       WHERE article_id = .$art_id ");
```

My question is: How can I use variables in a MySQL UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 13):

`$query = mysql_query("UPDATE article set com_count = $comments_count WHERE article_id = $art_id");`

You was messing up the quotes and concats.

You can use inline vars like the previous example or concat them like:

`$query = mysql_query("UPDATE article set com_count = " . $comments_count . " WHERE article_id = " . $art_id);`

Comment: believe me i would but ..it's said my reputation should be more than 15 ..and it doesn't ..sorry man

Comment: Here you go, now you have 16. Don't thank me, just accept the answer so the question could be marked as solved.

Answer (score 4):

You messed up on your `" .` pattern.

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE article set com_count = ". $comments_count . " WHERE article_id = " . $art_id . ");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use apostrophes when using variables in a MySQL UPDATE statement:

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE article 
                      SET com_count =  '$comments_count'
                      WHERE article_id = '$art_id'");
```

Be careful about space and apostrophes.