# Updating DB data from PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo, sql-update

I have a problem with variables in an SQL Statement. I have a form where a user can update his profile. The form redirects to `action.php?action=settings`

**When I try without $variables, there is no problem!** But the thing is, I have a lot of queries like this, but not for updating.

```
function change_user_data($trainer) {
    require("database.php");

    try {
        $results = $db->query("UPDATE trainer SET email='$email', status='$status', password='$password' WHERE name='$trainer'");        
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data could not be changed!";
        exit;
    }
}
```

and this is my `action.php`

```
if ($action == "settings")  {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    change_user_data($trainer);
}
```

When I `echo` those `$variables`, they get displayed so they are not empty. But this query updates my table but with no data, so everything is empty afterwards.

Comment: I'm not an expert in PHP, but from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838709/using-variables-in-mysql-update-php-mysql?rq=1), I think there is a problem with concatenating the data in the query. However, this seems prone to SQL injection and would be better to use [prepared statements](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is variable scope.

Variables defined outside of function cannot use in function except global variable or something.

You have two method.

First. If change_user_data function is in action.php file, add "global $email, $status, $password" like this:

```
function change_user_data($trainer) {

    global $email, $status, $password;

    require("database.php");

    try {
        $results = $db->query("UPDATE trainer SET email='$email', status='$status', password='$password' WHERE name='$trainer'");        
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data could not be changed!";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Or second. Pass the email, status, password data to function. Then you can use it.

Please check this manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: While your diagnosis is correct, the prescription might not be. Please don't advise the use of global variables for something that's so simple it can be done with adding parameters to the function

Comment: so this worked for me but i did it like Touregsys wrote: change_user_data($trainer, $email, $password, $status); I think this is the best way for things like that or what do you think? can you tell me why i should use global

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$results = $db->query("UPDATE trainer SET email='".$email."', status='".$status."', password='".$password."' WHERE name='".$trainer."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
change_user_data($trainer, $email, $password, $status);

function change_user_data($trainer, $email, $password, $status) {
    require("database.php");

    try {
        $results = $db->query("UPDATE trainer SET email='$email', status='$status', password='$password' WHERE name='$trainer'");        
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data could not be changed!";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After You Gettings Post varibles Then Check For those variables
whether those are empty or not
if not empty or NULL Then Update Database with Update Query With Non empty Variables

Answer (score 0):

May be

- Wrong data type of your columns. Check your table structure carefully. Example: if you set you column email as int then you cannot insert or update it's row value as text or letter
- Incorrect variables inside single quote. Try to concatenate variable and query string for better practice

If those don't work

Try to make mysql syntax error and check values of those variables, then you can define the error.

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

You have few problems with this function:

- Scoping issue, you did not pass all values
- You are vulnerable to sql injection
- You dont check if the record is updated

**function:**

```
function change_user_data($db, $params) {
    try {
        $sql = "UPDATE trainer SET email= ?, status=?, password=? WHERE name=?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
        $stmt->execute($params);
        $success = ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ? true : false;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Data could not be changed!";
        $success = false;
    }
return $success;
}
```

**Usage**

```
require("database.php");

$params = array($trainer, $email, $password, $status);
$user_data_updated = change_user_data($db, $params);

if($user_data_updated){
  echo 'user data updated';
}else{
  echo 'user data did not update';
}
```